# LU decomposition in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently having some probs with my code to decompose an array into an upper(u) and lower(l) array.

I am using the doolittle method

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    double a[10][10];
    double l[10][10];
    double u[10][10];
    double som=0;
    int RANG;
    cin >> RANG;
    for(int i=0; i<RANG; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<RANG;j++){
                    cin >> a[i][j];
            }
    }
    for(int i=0; i<RANG; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<RANG;j++){
                    u[i][j]=0;
                    l[i][j]=0;
            }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<RANG;i++) {
    l[i][i]=1;

        for(int j=i;j<RANG;j++) {
            for(int s=0;s<i-1;s++) {
                som+= l[i][s]*u[s][j];
            }
            u[i][j]=a[i][j]-som;
        }

        for(int k=i+1;k<RANG;k++) {
            double som=0;
            for(int s=0;s<i-1;s++) {
                som+=l[k][s]*u[s][i];
            }
            l[k][i]=(a[k][i]-som)/u[i][i];
        }
     }
     cout << "l:" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<RANG; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<RANG;j++){
                    cout << l[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
    }
    cout << "u: " << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<RANG; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<RANG;j++){
                    cout << u[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

plz help if you can...

PS: not sure if it belongs here, might be better on the mathematics site

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should use the debugger or print statements to identify at what point the behaviour diverges from what you expect, and then create a simplified test-case based around that.

Comment: I assume the dolittle approach is $O(n^2)$? Does anyone know of an $LU$ method that has a better order than $O(n^2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [http://download.intel.com/design/PentiumIII/sml/24504601.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20150701223512/http://download.intel.com/design/PentiumIII/sml/24504601.pdf) it got complete solution along with source code!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out QuantLib.  http://quantlib.org/index.shtml

Here's an example of code that uses the QuantLib library to decompose a 3x3 array.  It uses a Cholesky decomposition, but maybe it'll help.  http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/matrix-decomposition-with-quantlib/

Answer (score -3):

Check your 's' iteration it should be 
for(int s=0;s